# Formatting strings (%s) returns TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm trying to insert text into a large url with %s. Whenever I run it, I get the error: `TypeError: a float is required` which seems silly because I'm putting strings into strings and no floats or integers are involved. Any help would be awesome! My code is below

```
import datetime

date = (datetime.datetime.today().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=100)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
date = str(date)
date = date.replace("/","%2F")

def genUrl(account, date, lastName, firstName):
    url = "https://arpmp-ph.hidinc.com/arappl/bdarpdmq/pmqadhocrpt.html?a=&page=recipqry&disp-bdate=%s&disp-edate=%s&recip-list=02685245&output=web&dt-sort-by=rcpdt&mode=Recipient_Query&w_method=POST&suplist=BM0650386&base-prsb=0&base-phrm=0&base-recip=1&tot-recip=1&report=PHY&recip-sex=A&recip-dob=01%2F21%2F1964&account-id=%s&date=%s&dob-days=0&recip-name=%s&recip-fname=%s&enum-read-cnt=2&enum-keep-cnt=1&etime=5&pagename=pmqrecipqry&pdmdir=arpdm&pdmstate=ar&scriptname=%2Farappl%2Fbdarpdmq&exprecip=yes" %(date, str(datetime.datetime.now()), account, date, lastName, firstName)
    print(url)

genUrl("example",date, "Smith", "Jogn")
```

Sorry if I just made a stupid mistake and didn't notice it. I'm relatively new to Python

Comment: Aside: you probably want `html.escape` (or `cgi.escape` in older python versions).

Comment: Your url contains `%2F` which looks like Python string formatting syntax for a float.  You will need to escape any `%` signs in your strings as `%%` if you don't want them interpreter as python string formatting.

Comment: Note that there are *much* better ways to manipulate URL bits than raw string manipulation. Look at all the `urllib.parse` classes/functions.

Comment: As @larsks said, you're replacing with %2F which is a floating point declaration when Python does the string replacement. Also, I strongly advise using string interpolation or `.format()` instead of string formatting in Python 3.x

Comment: What is wrong with the peanut gallery on this website - why did this question deserve a downvote? It may be a menial question, sure, but come on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because you are replacing `"/"` with `"%2F"` which is the Python placeholder for floats.

[Use `.format()` instead of %](https://pyformat.info/):

```
import datetime

date = (datetime.datetime.today().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=100)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
date = str(date)
date = date.replace("/","%2F")

def genUrl(account, date, lastName, firstName):
    url = "https://arpmp-ph.hidinc.com/arappl/bdarpdmq/pmqadhocrpt.html?a=&page=recipqry&disp-bdate={}&disp-edate={}&recip-list=02685245&output=web&dt-sort-by=rcpdt&mode=Recipient_Query&w_method=POST&suplist=BM0650386&base-prsb=0&base-phrm=0&base-recip=1&tot-recip=1&report=PHY&recip-sex=A&recip-dob=01%2F21%2F1964&account-id={}&date={}&dob-days=0&recip-name={}&recip-fname={}&enum-read-cnt=2&enum-keep-cnt=1&etime=5&pagename=pmqrecipqry&pdmdir=arpdm&pdmstate=ar&scriptname=%2Farappl%2Fbdarpdmq&exprecip=yes".format(date, str(datetime.datetime.now()), account, date, lastName, firstName)
    print(url)

genUrl("example",date, "Smith", "Jogn")
```

Comment: It's not the replacement, it's the other hardcoded ones in the big long string that nobody wants to read.